# OAuth 2 scopes with decimal number to use bitwise mask

Tags: security, oauth, permissions, jwt, roles

My app uses Role based access control and to check the permissions it uses bitwise operations. The pseudo-code is something like:

```
function HasPermission(userPermission, permissionBitMask) {
    return (userPermission& permissionBitMask) != 0;
}
```

Now, I have decided to switch to OAuth 2 will be using JWT. As per the spec of OAuth 2:

> Scope is expressed as a set of case-sensitive and space-delimited
>   strings.

But I want to specify scope as a number, so instead of:

```
{
    scope: ["item:create", "item:view", "product:view"]
    // or an object based structure
}
```

I want to use:

```
{
    scope : 7
}
```

Is this design acceptable, what would I miss if I use case-sensitive strings instead. I suppose bitwise operator method should be more performant than string comparison and search which would be needed in latter case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of JWT the approach would be fine as claim values can be any JSON type so numbers are fine.

> For JWTs, while claim names are strings, claim values can be any JSON type.

(source: [JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#appendix-C)

However, if you have a requirement to stay compliant with OAuth2 then your proposal would not be acceptable. Staying compliant may be beneficial if you want to start with your own authorization server but want to keep your options open and easily switch to either a third-party authorization server hosted by you or a cloud authentication provider like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/). <sub>(Disclosure: I work at Auth0)</sub>

If I were you I would stay OAuth2 compliant even if I had no plans on switching implementations. It should be easy to implement a transformation from multiple `string` values to the integer used to represent the permissions. In the general scenario this simple transformation would never become the performance bottleneck of your application, but if you do have very specific performance requirements you can always include your integer in the JWT as a `string`:

```
{ scope: "7" }
```

This way you'll be OAuth2 compliant and can use just a simple parsing operation to convert to a value usable for your bitwise comparisons.

Comment: I have no issues using integer as string if it makes it compliant. By the way I  use Auth0 for one of my projects, but it can't be used if you offer on-premise installation of your web app